# Java API for PDF signing (no iText allowed)

Tags: java, pdf, certificate, sign

I want to use a Java API that allows me to sign PDF documents. Everybody talks about iText, but it has a line on its license license that, just plain sucks:

> In accordance with Section 7(b) of the GNU Affero General Public License, you must retain the producer line in every PDF that is created or manipulated using iText.

Is there an alternative? All I found so far are iText wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if any of these have signing, but here is a [list](http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries) of open source offerings.

BTW, all I've ever used is iText.

Answer (score 1):

You didnt tell the whole story about Itext licensing. If you pay, that notice disappears.

Comment: That's not an answer, that's a comment.

Comment: @owlstead it addresses the main core of the q. To solve the problem of removing the notice, buy a license, its a perfect valid solution. The q does not say it simply wants another lib, it only hates the notice.

Comment: True, on the other hand, it explicitly says "no iText allowed" in the title. Suggesting a payed version of iText is therefore not really relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try PDFBox from Apache ..

check this sample https://stackoverflow.com/a/13387484/2267723

or try the old version of [iText 2.1.7](http://olex.openlogic.com/package_versions/download/9132?package_version_id=2802&path=https://olex-secure.openlogic.com/content/openlogic/itext/2.1.7/openlogic-itext-2.1.7-all-bin-1.zip) (GPL), here is a nice example: [click](http://www.berthou.com/us/2007/11/28/sign-a-pdf-document/). just to know that the working version of BouncyCastle you would need is bcprov JDK15, 1.46 : [download](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15+/1.46/bcprov-jdk15+-1.46.jar)

good luck